A movie about a widow haunted by the spirit of her dead husband
I don't remember too many assets about this movie, I was pretty young when I saw it on late-TV while going through channels.
Plot and scene description
I remember a little bit of the plot, it was the story of a woman (I don't remember her appearance) that lost her husband, and she was being haunted by him. 
One thing that is still pretty clear on my mind is the scene when the widow is about to have sex with another man and suddenly the guy starts taking punches out of thin air (punches from the dead husband spirit), after many blows this guy is slammed to the wall (facing the wall) and his arm starts coming up through his back, making a lot of bone-snapping sounds and eventually breaking it. After that scene I think that his arm was ripped off, but it's still a little bit fuzzy on my memory.
There was a little portrait with the picture of the couple that always appeared whenever something weird happened on the house that could relate to this dead-husband-evil-spirit.
When was the movie released
I was watching it when I was a kid (around 10 years old), I wish I could give more details about it, but I don't know if the memories I have are actually from the movie or from the nightmares I've got after watching it (I wasn't a big fan of horror before, hehe). A good guess would be a 90s-80s movie.
Language of the movie
Pretty sure it was English (US)

100 Feet

After Marnie Watson kills her abusive husband in self-defense, she is condemned to house arrest... only to discover that the house is possessed by the enraged and violent spirit of her dead husband




Here's "the punching scene" you're describing 




Omg, incredible!!
I could swear that it was an older movie. But you guessed it perfectly! Thank you very much.
(Geez, the brutal punching scene is even more bloody than I remembered, no wonder my brain deleted most of it).
